# .htaccess only do rule if both conditions are met

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/((\w+))?$ ?page=$1&other=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)(/(\w+))?$ ?page=$1&other=$3 [L]
```

What this does is make it so if a user puts in **mysite.com/blarg** and /blarg isn't a real directory OR file, it will send thme to **index.php?page=blarg**.

But when I go to **mysite.com/iphone** (which is a real directory, but not a file) I am directed to **mysite.com/iphone/?page=iphone&other=**

Answer (score 0):

It is because presence of the last `RewriteRule` line with `RewriteCond`. Keep in mind that `RewriteCond` is applicable for very next `RewriteRule` only.

Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/((\w+))?$ ?page=$1&other=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)(/(\w+))?$ ?page=$1&other=$3 [L]
```